# Pass Go Pointer via "cgo" as a Key

Tags: python, go, cgo

I am doing some interop between Go and Python. I am planning on creating objects in the Go land and only access them from Python through Go methods. For example, `struct A` below will only be created and destroyed in the Go land and only be accessed through `method1`. But Python code does need to know the handle/pointer to instances of `struct A` such that when it passes this handle/pointer to a Go function, the Go function knows to convert it to a Go pointer and calls its method. In other words, Python does not directly use the Go pointer `*A` as a pointer that references/dereferences memory, but rather uses it as a key to identify the Go objects.

The problem is that it is not valid to do `int(a)` for `var a *A` and I cannot directly pass `*A` between cgo methods.

What can I do so that I can convert `*A` to some blackbox key that is an integer and later convert it back to `*A` ?

```
type A struct {
    a int
}

func (a *A) method1(){
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** you can't really.

Longer answer, is that because Go is garbage collected, you're able to pass pointers to C, but it must C must preserve this property: C should not store any Go pointers in Go memory, even temporarily, and may not keep a copy of a Go pointer after a call returns.

You can read a much more about the handling and uses in the cgo documentation https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers , which may help you with your usecase, maybe.

Comment: The document talks about using the Go pointer actually as a pointer in C, which makes sense that the C program should not keep a copy in memory due to GC. However, my use case is much like using the pointer as a key to the Go map `map[*Object] Values`, as C never uses the pointer to reference/dereference memory. It's kind of odd that there is no way to use the Go pointer as a key for some data structure in C.